# Showing coordinates of a point in a Graphics3D object with cursor scrolling over it

Tags: graphics3d, mesh

I would like to know how one can coax Mathematica to reveal the coordinates of a generic `Graphics3D` object. Consider, e.g., the unit sphere:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[]]
```

[image]

I realise that the first step is probably to generate a discrete mesh of the object using `DiscretizeGraphics[]`, but what next?

[image]

---

**EDIT:**
I apologise, I was vague about what I really wanted. What I really need is the ability to see the coordinates of each point as I am scrolling over it, like in regular 2d plots. Is that possible?

Note: There is already a question on this topic ([Seeing coordinates in Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113896/seeing-coordinates-in-graphics3d)) from 2016, but it's only meant for line segments, and thus does not serve my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the desired results using Ulrich Neumann's answer, and Algohi's answer in [How can I add labels to the points in my scatterplot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60814/how-can-i-add-labels-to-the-points-in-my-scatterplot)

I mesh the `Graphics3D` object, get its coordinates, plot a 3d scatter plot using `ListPointPlot3D`, and use `Tooltip` to display its coordinates:

```
pic = DiscretizeGraphics[ Graphics3D[Sphere[]]]
coords=pic["Coordinates"]
ListPointPlot3D[MapThread[Tooltip, {coords, coords}]]

Show[%, pic]
```

So, for example, for a sliver of a cone:

[image]

I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
pic = DiscretizeGraphics[ Graphics3D[Sphere[]]]


pic["Coordinates"]
```

gives you all the points of the surface!

More information concerning `pic` you can fin with `pic["Properties"]`

Comment: Thank you. Ideally, would it be possible to display the coordinates of each point as I am scrolling over it?

Comment: In fact, that is really the question I had. Let me edit my question in order to reflect that. Sorry for the confusion; I really appreciate the first step you have provided here.

Comment: @ap21 If you scroll over the 2D image of the sphere how to decide which of the two 3D points is the right one?

Comment: Good point. But I am taking my cue from software like Matlab, where it is possible to scroll over a point in 3d and get its coordinates. I know it is tricky, and one has to play around to get the good coordinates, but if Matlab has a solution, so should Mathematica. That's why I was asking.